not all images visible on image slider website
I am working on an image slider website. It has two problems:

The button to slide the images forward are working but the images are not shown.
The button to slide the images backward gets unclickable because it is behind the image element (even though the image is not shown).

This is the JavaScript code:
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');
    const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');

    let currentSlide = 0;
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    const totalSlides = slides.length;

    window.addEventListener('load', updateSlider);
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateSlider);

    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % totalSlides;
        updateSlider();
    });

    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentSlide = (currentSlide - 1 + totalSlides) % totalSlides;
        updateSlider();
    });

    function updateSlider() {
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentSlide * 100}%)`;
        // slider.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
        console.log(`Current Slide: ${currentSlide}`);
    }

    // Initial call to ensure the slider is set correctly on load
    updateSlider();
});

The codepen URL is here: codepen
I have used console.log() to debug and identified the problem but not sure how to find a solution.

1. There is a problem with your image relative reference in the HTML.
For example, if you replace this:
<div class="slide"><img src="images/image-1.png" alt="Image 1"></div>

To this:
<div class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/road-sign-361514_640.png" alt="Image 1"></div>

It will work correctly.
Make sure your image is in a folder named "images" and the file name is "image1.png" (or "image2.png", etc.), starting from the same location as your HTML file.
You can read more about it here.
2. You need to change the z-index of the class .nav-btn to assure that it will be always on the top:
.nav-btn {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}

Note: Using a very high z-index might affect other elements on your page, so choose a value that achieves your desired stacking order without causing unintended consequences.
